# Cannot correctly resize an image via action script

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, image-resizing

Hi I am trying to add an image when I click on a thumbnail.
I know I have to use a listener (Event.COMPLETE ?), but the image is not resizing correctly when I rotate the tablet.

I believe the problem is that I cannot resize the image within the addImage1() function, as the image has not yet loaded, but I cannot use newImg.width within the listener function to reset the image width.

Any help would be most appreciated. 
Code follows:-)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="ZOOM Pictues with Tap"
    resize="view1_resizeHandler(event)">

<s:layout>
      <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Declarations>
      <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

     <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

    import mx.events.FlexEvent;
    import mx.events.ResizeEvent;

    public var hasImageBeenAdded:Boolean = false;
    private var imageLastWidth:Number;
    private var imageLastHeight:Number;
    private var zoomFactor:Number;
    private var imageNumber:Number;

    private var rhsKeepWidth:int;
    private var rhsKeepHeight:int;
    private var rhsKeep:Boolean = false;

    protected function view1_resizeHandler(event:ResizeEvent):void
    {

      if(rhsKeepWidth > rhsKeepHeight) // Was Landscape is now Portrait
      {
        var tmpWidth2:int = rhsKeepWidth;
        var tmpHeight2:int = rhsKeepHeight;
        rhsKeepWidth = tmpHeight2-lhs.width;
        rhsKeepHeight = tmpWidth2+lhs.width;                
      }
      else //Was Portrait is now Landscape
      {
        var tmpWidth1:int = rhsKeepWidth;
        var tmpHeight1:int = rhsKeepHeight;
        rhsKeepWidth = tmpHeight1-lhs.width;
        rhsKeepHeight = tmpWidth1+lhs.width;
      } 
      addImage1();
    }

    protected function removeAllImages():void
    {       
      var totalElements : int = rhs.numElements;
      for(var i:int=totalElements-1;i>=0;i--)
      {
        rhs.removeElementAt(i);
      }
    }

    private function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void
    {
      var zoomFactor1:Number;
      var zoomFactor2:Number;

      imageLastWidth = e.target.sourceWidth;
      imageLastHeight = e.target.sourceHeight;

      if(rhsKeep != true) //Need to set the rhs VGroup dimensions
      {
        rhs.width = hGroup1.width-lhs.width;
        rhs.height = hGroup1.height;
        rhsKeep = true;
        rhsKeepWidth = rhs.width;
        rhsKeepHeight = rhs.height;
      }

      zoomFactor1 = rhsKeepWidth/imageLastWidth;
      zoomFactor2 = rhsKeepHeight/imageLastHeight;

      if(zoomFactor1 < zoomFactor2)
      {
        zoomFactor = zoomFactor1;
      }
      else
      {
        zoomFactor = zoomFactor2;
      }
      trace("zoomFactor=" + zoomFactor);
    }

    public function addImage1():void
    {
      var i:int;
      var newImg:Image = new Image();
      removeAllImages();
      newImg.source = "images/1.jpg";
      newImg.x = 0;
      newImg.y = 0;
      newImg.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onImageLoaded);
      rhs.addElementAt(newImg,0);
      hasImageBeenAdded = true;
      imageNumber = 1;
      trace("Image Width= " + newImg.width);
      newImg.scaleX = newImg.scaleY = zoomFactor;
    }

    ]]>
     </fx:Script>


    <s:HGroup id="hGroup1" width="100%" height="100%">      
      <s:Scroller id="scrollerL"  height="100%">
        <s:VGroup id="lhs" width="15%" height="100%" gap="10" 
        horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="top">
          <s:Image width="100" height="100" source="thumbs/1.jpg" click="addImage1()"/>
      </s:VGroup>
      </s:Scroller>

      <s:Scroller id="scroller1" height="100%" width="100%">
        <s:VGroup id="rhs" height="100%">
        </s:VGroup>
      </s:Scroller>
     </s:HGroup>


    </s:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the device orientation, you should use:

```
trace(Stage.deviceOrientation);
trace(Stage.orientation);
```

They are read-only strings outputting information regarding the device's and the screen's orientation. You may manually set the stage's orientation:

```
Stage.setOrientation(StageOrientation.DEFAULT);
```

---

Regarding the image loading, you need an eventListener for Event.COMPLETE and you should also cast the content as Image:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(event:Event):void {
    trace("Image loaded");
    // Handle code here
    // Use: (loader.content as Image)
});
loader.load(new URLRequest("images/1.jpg"));
```